# Hibernate duplicates cols in table with PUT request

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

[image]

I have two related tables Sizes and Goods
One good can have many sizes
When I send request for editing one of fields of good, It returns duplicated sizes object

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "title": "Barnaul 2",
    "sex": "CHILD",
    "manufacturer": {
      "id": 1,
      "manufacturerName": "Ralf",
      "address": "Moscow",
      "telephone": "9-999-999-99-99"
    },
    "manufacturerId": 1,
    "sizes": [
      {
        "size": 39,
        "quantity": 4
      },
      {
        "size": 37,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

For example, I have 37 and 39 sizes and I change one of them for another (e.g. 40) In result I will have:

```
"sizes": [
      {
        "size": 39,
        "quantity": 4
      },
      {
        "size": 37,
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "size": 39,
        "quantity": 4
      },
      {
        "size": 40,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  }
```

And there are my entities

Good:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "goods")
    public class Good {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

//    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
//    @Column(name = "sex")
//    private sexType sexType;

    @Column(name = "sex")
    private String sex;

    /**
     * proved and it actually works!
     */
    //@JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "ManufacturerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Manufacturer manufacturer; //Many goods can refer to one manufacturer

    @Column(name = "manufacturerId")
    private int manufacturerId;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "good")//Uni-directional reference to size array
    List<Size> sizes; //Change CascadeType in case delete size cause deletion of Good (in future)

    public void addSizeToGood(Size size) {
        if (sizes == null) sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        sizes.add(size);
        size.setGood(this);
    }

    //Constructors
    public Good() {

    }

    public Good(String title, String sex, Manufacturer manufacturer, List<Size> sizes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.sizes = sizes;
    }
```

Size:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sizes")
public class Size {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Size")
    private int size;

    @Column(name = "Quantity")
    private int quantity;

    @Column(name = "goodid", insertable = false, updatable = false) //Check else
    private int goodId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "goodId")
    Good good;

    //Constructors
    public Size() {

    }

    public Size(int size, int quantity) {
        this.size = size;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

DAO:

```
@Override
    public void saveGood(Good good) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        System.out.println(good);
        session.merge(good); //SaveOrUpdate substitute
    }
```

Controller:

```
@PatchMapping("/goods")
    public Good updateGood(@RequestBody Good good) {
        goodService.saveGood(good);
        return good;
    }
```

I have two ideas, but I don't know, how to contribute them:

1. Somehow add deleting of previos fields and write new size object
2. Change rules for editing

I asked this question ~5 days ago, but there weren't working advice

Comment: @fascynacja no, I wrote in last paragraph that I asked this question but noting helped me

Comment: There is a concept called Open Session in View. This could be the troublemaker in this scenario. I'm not sure but i think it is worth a try.